# PHP date function to extract a raw timestamp?

Tags: php, php-5.4

I want to convert a human readable date time such as `20210419115522` to `2021-04-19 11:55:22` via `PHP`. How is it possible?

```
<?php
echo date('Ymd', 20210419115301);   <------ Not the result I expect
```

Comment: See [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ex: $time = strtotime("20210419115301");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);